# How do I make text slide to the right upon page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, text, sliding

I'm not fluent in javascript and I'm trying to edit [this example at w3schools](http://w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1_multicss) to make a simple headline within a div slide to the right smoothly (from out of view) upon page load. I just KNOW it has something to do with the code that is already here, but I'm having two problems.

1. When I turn the box they are moving into a text headline and change the "div" selector into '.headline' (or whatever I've named it), clicking the button won't move it.
2. If I figure that out, I still don't know how to make it work without the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now that code is invoked with a click handler, just remove the wrapper for that and execute it on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".header").animate({ //be sure to change the class of your element to "header"
        left:'250px',
        opacity:'0.5',
        height:'150px',
        width:'150px'
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/ZWtQw/1/

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make it when body loads just try these
100% working
The html content and coding are as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

var function1 = function(){ 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").animate({

      left:'250px',
      opacity:'0.5',
      height:'150px',
      width:'150px'
    });
});

};
</script> 
</head>

<body onload="function1();">

<p> in the body tag  i have added onload event which tells that when body is fully loaded then do this function which has a name of function1 or you can name something else but remember <b>in script tag the name after var should be same as the name in onload event   </b></p>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could elaborate on how / why they work the way they do, possibly a jsfiddle.